# love2d - update the text of printed text

Tags: text, lua, updates, love2d

I have printed text that says "Yes". and I have to buttons in the shape of arrow. I am trying to get it so that if I click the left arrow it say "No" and if I click the right arrow is says "Yes".

```
fsdefault = "Yes"
fs = love.graphics.print(fsdefault, 440, 160)
love.graphics.draw(larrow, 425, 163)
love.graphics.draw(rarrow, 470, 163)

function love.update(dt)
function love.mousepressed( x, y)
    if x > 424 and x < 435 and y > 161 and y < 172 then 
        fsdefault = "No"
    end

    if x > 275 and x < 320 and y > 305 and y < 325 then 
        fsdefault = "Yes"
    end
end
end
```

Comment: `x > 424 and x < 335`. Chose an `x`. Would it ever satisfy both of the conditions?

Comment: Sorry. it was meant to be 435. original post has been edited

Answer (score 1):

How about something like:

```
local fsdefault = ""
function love.mousepressed( x, y)
    if x > 424 and x < 435 and y > 161 and y < 172 then 
        fsdefault = "No"
    end

    if x > 275 and x < 320 and y > 305 and y < 325 then 
        fsdefault = "Yes"
    end
end

function love.draw()
    love.graphics.print(fsdefault, 440, 160)
    love.graphics.draw(larrow, 425, 163)
    love.graphics.draw(rarrow, 470, 163)
end
```

Note that for clarity, you should only perform screen drawing operations inside `love.draw`.

Also, try to avoid declaring functions inside `love.update`. That code snippet will make love redefine `love.mousepressed` every single frame of your game!